# Configuring remote access when using a VPN

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, remote-access, raspberry-pi

To address some of the responsiveness issues, I use the Mathematica front end (v9 or v10) to access a remote kernel on a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/).  The (advanced) kernel configuration used is this:

**Arguments to MLOpen:**

> -LinkMode Listen -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkOptions MLDontInteract

**Shell command to launch kernel:**

> "`java`" -jar "`mathssh`" pi@lcdlab sudo wolfram -mathlink -LinkMode Connect -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkName "`linkname`" -LinkHost `ipaddress`

I recently subscribed to a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) service with this company: [Private Internet Access](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/). Connecting through the VPN breaks my ability to access the remote kernel.  I only have the VPN running on my PC, not on the RPi.

Debugging a bit, I notice this process on the RPi

> sudo wolfram -mathlink -LinkMode Connect -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkName 3273@*[local ip]*,3274@*[local ip]* -LinkHost *[private ip]*

where *[local ip]* is the IP address assigned by my router to my PC and *[private ip]* is an address from a private block (10.0...) that I assume is being assigned via my VPN.  Therefore, I conclude that communication is only one-way, since the RPi doesn't know to whom it's talking.

I can work around this problem by hard coding the *[local ip]* into the shell command:

**Shell command to launch kernel: (workaround)**

> "`java`" -jar "`mathssh`" pi@lcdlab sudo wolfram -mathlink -LinkMode Connect -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkName "`linkname`" -LinkHost *[local ip]*

This workaround is sufficient for my current configuration; however I would like to know if there is some solution that does not require manual configuration of the shell command.  It is clear that `linkname` contains the necessary IP address, however it also contains ports that should not be passed to `-LinkHost`.  Is there a way to parse `linkname` and use that as the argument for `-LinkHost`?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, saved me a lot of time!